Adding JS function to a checkbox to prompt a new HTML element if TRUE
I'm developing some web page examples for my own practice, and would like to have this form contain a JS function, that prompts a 'corrective action' area when the 'X' is checked. See code and CSS below.


function checkMe() {
  var cb = document.getElementById("registration-danger");
  var ca = document.getElementById("correctiveAction");
  if (cb.checked == true) {
    ca.style.display = "block";
    console.log('true');
  } else {
    ca.style.display = "none";
    console.log('false');
  }
}
<!--Registration Line-->
<div class="accordion-body vehicleBody border border-light-subtle">

  <h3 id="registration" class="mx-3">Current / Valid Vehicle Registration
    <span>
        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="registration" id="registration-success" autocomplete="off" >
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-circle" for="registration-success"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></label>

        <input onclick="checkMe()" type="radio" class="btn-check" name="registration" id="registration-danger" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-danger rounded-circle ms-3" for="registration-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i></label>
    </span>
  </h3>
  <div class="ms-3" id="correctiveAction">
    <p class="text-center" style="font-weight: 400; padding: 10px; color: crimson; text-decoration: underline;">Corrective Action Required!</p>

    <div class="form-floating correctiveAction">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="floatingTextarea2" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
      <label for="floatingTextarea2">Please determine appropriate corrective action.</label>



I tried using this JS function. It works when the button is checked, i've confirmed this in the console. However, it doesn't log 'false' when the button isn't clicked, or unclicked.

Use a change event listener on the checkbox. It can check whether the checkbox is now checked. If so, it shows the prompt field, otherwise it hides the prompt.

If you want more specific help, you need to post what you tried, and we'll help you fix it.

appreciate the advice! I'm going to play around this evening and try to target the checkboxes. Like i said, pretty new to JS but i have a number of notes I can review on element selectors and what not.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Hi @Barmar , I have updated my code with the JS i have tried to link.

You need to call checkMe() when you click on the other radio button as well.

BTW, radio buttons are not checkboxes.

You need to call the function when you click on either radio button, so it will run when you deselect the option by clicking on the other button. So add the same onclick to the other button.


function checkMe() {
  var cb = document.getElementById("registration-danger");
  var ca = document.getElementById("correctiveAction");
  if (cb.checked == true) {
    ca.style.display = "block";
    console.log('true');
  } else {
    ca.style.display = "none";
    console.log('false');
  }
}
<!--Registration Line-->
<div class="accordion-body vehicleBody border border-light-subtle">

  <h3 id="registration" class="mx-3">Current / Valid Vehicle Registration
    <span>
        <input onclick="checkMe()" type="radio" class="btn-check" name="registration" id="registration-success" autocomplete="off" >
        <label class="btn btn-outline-success rounded-circle" for="registration-success"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></label>

        <input onclick="checkMe()" type="radio" class="btn-check" name="registration" id="registration-danger" autocomplete="off" />
        <label class="btn btn-outline-danger rounded-circle ms-3" for="registration-danger"><i class="fa-solid fa-x"></i></label>
    </span>
  </h3>
  <div class="ms-3" id="correctiveAction">
    <p class="text-center" style="font-weight: 400; padding: 10px; color: crimson; text-decoration: underline;">Corrective Action Required!</p>

    <div class="form-floating correctiveAction">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="floatingTextarea2" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
      <label for="floatingTextarea2">Please determine appropriate corrective action.</label>



